# How can perform an Elasticsearch Multisearch, with only suggesters?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to return suggestions from 4 separate suggesters, across two separate indices.

I am currently doing this by sending two separate requests to Elasticsearch (one for each index) and combining the results in my application.  Obviously this does not seem ideal when the Multisearch API is available.

From playing with the Multisearch API I am able to combine these suggestion requests into one and it correctly retrieves results from all 4 completion suggesters from both indexes.

However, it also automatically performs a `match_all` query on the chosen indices.  I can of course minimize the impact of this by setting `searchType` to `count` but the results are worse than the two separate curl requests.

It seems that no matter what I try I cannot prevent the Multisearch API from performing some sort of query over each index.

e.g.

```
  {
       index: 'users',
       type: 'user'
  },
  {
      suggest: {
            users_suggest: {
                 text: term,
                 completion: {
                     size : 5,
                     field: 'users_suggest'
                 }
      }
  },
 {
       index: 'photos',
       type: 'photo'
 },
 {
      suggest: {
            photos_suggest: {
                 text: term,
                 completion: {
                     size : 5,
                     field: 'photos_suggest'
                 }
            }
      }
 }
```

A request like the above which clearly omits the `{query:{}` part of this multisearch request, still  performs a `match_all` query and returns everything in the index.

Is there any way to prevent the query taking place so that I can simply get the combined completion suggesters results?  Or is there another way to search multiple suggesters on multiple indices in one query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do make size=0, so that no hits will be returned but only suggestions.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "suggest":{}
}
```

for every request.

Comment: Doing exactly as you have suggested does indeed prevent the results from being returned however it still returns a total count.  This implies to me that Elasticsearch is still performing some unneeded work in the same way as if I had simply set the searchType to count.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, If you have a search request then elasticsearch will search the documents by default, and does other operation (aggregating , faceting  and suggesting) if specified. The thing is, if we don't want any document(specifying size=0) then the operation is executed in small amount of time.